# Can I use a global variable instead of state to store a value which changes?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react andI wanted to know if I can just store a value which changes for each render in a global variable. I know we use states so that the component renders after a change in state but if I didnt want to render again can I just use a global variable? will this work and is it a bad practice to do so?

Couldnt find a good explanation for this

Comment: It does not work, React "reacts" only to changing props or state. That's why global state management libraries like redux have tools to copy global state into local component props or state, to trigger re-rendering.

Comment: @timotgl I undetstand global variable wont trigger re-rendering but will it be able to store values which I set inside the local scope?

Comment: Yeah, global variables are accessible from anywhere, hence the name. It is mostly considered bad practice though to do this in a browser environment, you have to worry about naming collisions etc. if you use something like `window.myGlobalData` - if you must use a global var for that, consider using a module with a dedicated getter and setter to access it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not fully understand the question.

What you mean is if the variables like const hold a value and this value will not change in every rendering everything is ok.

Comment: Please consider adding a comment to OP's questions before posting an answer. SO is different from forums/bulletin boards in that regard.

Comment: no not a constant variable a normal variable whose value is updated . will that work?